# Inspecting a variable appears to be changing the behaviour of a run

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm debugging the following code.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<LinkedList<FileInfo>>> cache = emptyCache();

private void addToCache(final FileInfo fileInfo) {
  final int first = 0xFF & Byte.valueOf(fileInfo.getFirstByteFromMiddle());
  final int second = 0xFF & Byte.valueOf(fileInfo.getSecondByteFromMiddle());

  if (first < 0 || second < 0)
    System.err.println("error");

  cache.get(first).get(second).add(fileInfo);
}
```

Without a breakpoint set on `System.err.println("error")`, this is what I observe on the console.

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:58469,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Users/petur/Development/Einfalda/einfalda/target/classes:/Users/petur/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.0/commons-collections4-4.0.jar:/Users/petur/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" eu.petur.einfalda.Einfalda /Users/petur/Documents
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58469', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58469', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -125
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:418)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:431)
    at eu.petur.einfalda.DupFinder.addToCache(DupFinder.java:94)
    at eu.petur.einfalda.DupFinder.findDuplicates(DupFinder.java:30)
    at eu.petur.einfalda.Einfalda.main(Einfalda.java:23)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

However, If I set a breakpoint on the line with `System.err.println("error")` the program runs fine and exits with `Process finished with exit code 0`.
Likewise if I use `System.out.println` to display the values of those two varialbes, just after they have been set.

Why can I not reproduce the bug when a variable is inspected before its used?

Comment: I'm using `0xFF&` to convert the domain of a Byte from [-128;127] to [0;∞).

Comment: Is the code being used in a concurrent environment?

Comment: Maybe it runs _too_ fast?

Comment: Adding a breakpoint causes the program to wait..

Comment: Maybe your breakpoint is allowing time for some background task to complete? You could try adding a `Thread.sleep(10000);` after `System.err.println("error");`.  This would make your method pause for 10 seconds, most likely giving time to what needs to execute to run.

Comment: @chris There is no concurrency.

Comment: @Pétur How do you know? It can be one of the method you're using that starts different threads.

Comment: try printing out the values of `Byte.valueOf(...)` before the conversion. They should have the same values between normal mode and debug mode

Comment: What is `FileInfo`? Which line from the stacktrace is in the posted code snippet?

Comment: @SubOptimal `fileInfo.getSecondByteFromMiddle()` returns a value in range [-128;127]

Comment: Negative values are not possible to use with `ArrayList.get()` that's what you see in your stacktrace `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -125`. Start searching from that point and not on the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by disabling JIT using `-Djava.compiler=NONE` as a VM option. I can only imagine the issue has to do with optimization.